# Does the Jackpot II Merit Award Affect the Glim Reaper Trophy?

Tags: achievements, ni-no-kuni-wrath-of-the-white-witch

I was awarded the **[Little Battler Experience](http://psnprofiles.com/trophy/1806-Ni-no-Kuni-Wrath-of-the-White-Witch/13-Little-Battler-Experience)** trophy (*awarded for winning 1,000 battles*) what feels like at least a few dozen fights ago, but have yet to see the **[Glim Reaper](http://psnprofiles.com/trophy/1806-Ni-no-Kuni-Wrath-of-the-White-Witch/12-Glim-Reaper)** trophy pop.  Since there are typically at least 2+ glims remaining at the end of each battle, I'm wondering if the **Jackpot II** merit award affects the count:

> Allows you to collect any glims that remain at the end of a battle
>   automatically.

Do you actually have to collect these during the battle? Do the glims that you automatically collect at the end of a fight count or not?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Based on my experience, the glims that are collected automatically at the end of a battle *do count* toward the Glim Reaper trophy, along with any that you collected yourself during the battle. However, any glims that are collected by one of your AI compatriots (e.g. when Oliver or his familiars collect glims while you are playing as Esther) *do not count*.